# ffmpeg scale, overlap & opacity

Tags: ffmpeg

How do I chain several filters into one video?
Basically - I have an overlay image (transparent gif), want to center it, and apply an opacity of 30% to the gif. This is what I have:

ffmpeg -i inputmovie.mov -i transparentgif.gif -filter_complex "[0]scale=1280:-2[bg];[bg][1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-200:main_h-overlay_h-200" -b:v 1500k outputvideo.mp4

(Basically, I want the output video to be 1280x760 (input is 4k)
then the gif overlay to be centered, and specify the alpha/opacity/transparency).

But I am not sure how/where to add this in that command line:
blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=0.3[v]

Could you please help? Thanks very much!

PPS - what would be REALLY nice is if there was some kind of way I could do this in "batch", i.e.,
say: video1.mov
video2.mov
etc
and output it as
output_video1.mov
output_video2.mov
etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there. You can use the colorchannelmixer filter to set transparency for the GIF.

`ffmpeg -i inputmovie.mov -i transparentgif.gif -filter_complex "[0]scale=1280:-2[bg];[1]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.3[gif];[bg][gif]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" -b:v 1500k outputvideo.mp4`

Comment: awesome! one last question (I added a pps, so not sure if you saw it before I edited it) - do you know how I can now "batch" these videos, so it just goes through my directory doing the videos, and then say appending an 'output' name, or something? i.e., "input=videos*.mp4" and output = "?????_outputvideo.mp4"? thx!

Comment: ffmpeg can't do that but you can write a script or batch file for whichever shell you're using where you use a for loop and substitute file names.